# Heap's Algorithm Walk-Through

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, heaps-algorithm

So, I'm learning recursion, and I'm working on a coding challenge that requires all variations of elements in an array.

I was pointed to [Heap's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm) and this is what I've drawn up so far in JavaScript.

```
function generate(n, array) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return array;
    }
    else {
        for (var i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            generate(n - 1, array);
            if (n % 2 == 0) {
                swap(array[i], array[n - 1]);
            }
            else {
                swap(array[0], array[n - 1]);
            }
        }
        generate(n - 1, array);
    }
}
```

**Please ignore** the fact that I haven't translated the "swap" instances to JavaScript.

I'm a bit unsure as **how to exactly walk-through the recursive part of this algorithm**.

Say I have the array: **[A,B,C,D,E]**.  I believe that the arguments I would pass into the outer function would be:

```
generate(5, [A,B,C,D,E]);
```

In this case, n is not equal to 1, so I would move on to the "else" portion.
I encounter the for-loop and, because n is 5, it executes.

Next: The function calls itself, but this time the arguments are:

```
generate(4, [A,B,C,D,E]);
```

**This is where my confusion begins**:

As I'm walking through this, do I move on to the "if"/"else" conditions
 or do I (after the recursive call) go back up to the very start of the outer function?

**Update**

Below is the totally translated JavaScript version of Heap's algorithm.

```
function generate(n, array) {
//console.log("ENTER", n, array)

if (n == 1) {

    console.log(array);
}

else {

    for (var i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        //console.log("RECUR", n-1, array)


        generate(n - 1, array);

        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            //console.log("SWAP ", n, array)

            var one = array[i];
            var two = array[n - 1];

            array[i] = two;

            array[n - 1] = one;

            //swap(array[i], array[n - 1]);
        }

        else {
            //console.log("SWAP ", 0, n-1)

            var first = array[0];
            var second = array[n - 1];

            array[0] = second;

            array[n - 1] = first;


            //swap(array[0], array[n - 1]);
        }
         //console.log("array", array)
    }

    //console.log("RECUR 2", n-1, array)

    generate(n - 1, array);
}

//console.log("LEAVE", n, array)
```

}

I was walking through it on paper until I reached a point where I got a repeat, [A,B,C,D] again.

Thinking I messed up, I decided to implement Prune's suggestion of console outputs to see what was happening in the console and it was helpful.

After fixing a small error, it's working just fine now.

**Thanks to everyone that helped!**

Comment: When your called function returns a value, you move on, you don't start back from the beginning.

Comment: @vic3685 - I'm guessing I won't be able to move on to the "if" statement in the for-loop until the point where generate(n - 1, array) is: 
generate(2  - 1, array), because that is when it'll return something (1)....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My canonical answer at this point is, if you're having trouble walking through the algorithm on paper, *don't*!  Make the computer do it for you.  Insert a bunch of **console.log** commands to trace the execution.  Trace the entry and exit of each routine and call, including useful values.

```
function generate(n, array) {
    console.log("ENTER", n, array)
    if (n == 1) {
        return array;
    }
    else {
        for (var i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            console.log("RECUR", n-1, array)
            generate(n - 1, array);
            if (n % 2 !== 0) {
                console.log("SWAP ", n, array)
                swap(array[i], array[n - 1]);
            }
            else {
                console.log("SWAP ", 0, n-1)
                swap(array[0], array[n - 1]);
            }
            console.log("array", array)
        }
        console.log("RECUR 2", n-1, array)
        generate(n - 1, array);
    }
    console.log("LEAVE", n, array)
}
```

This will give you a lovely execution trace.  For even greater readability, indent each line of output 2*(5-n) spaces.

Comment: You'll need to implement `swap` properly to make this useful

Comment: @Prune - I added an update to my post and would really appreciate your thoughts on it, thanks!

Comment: Thoughts such as what?  That's a very open comment for SO.

Answer (score 1):

let me enumerate your lines, so we can refer to them easier (see below)

you walked from `generate(5, [A,B,C,D,E]);` up to `generate(4, [A,B,C,D,E]);` (at line 7) and then you entered `generate` for a 2nd time, without having finished your 1st call, so you put pause to the 1st call and start walking with the 2nd one

now (2nd call) `n=4` so you get to line 7 again, but this time a 3rd call `generate(3, [A,B,C,D,E])` starts (without finishing previous ones)

same goes for a 4th call `generate(2, ...)` and yet a 5th call `generate(1, ...)` which is when things start to change

in the 5th call `n=1`, so condition at line 2 evals true and `array` is returned, and we are back to where we came from, which is, the 4th call at line 7, where the returned array makes nothing (it is not assigned or anything) and then we reach line 8 (for the first time) while in the 4th call, `n=2` therefore second `swap` happends and `i` is incremented, and back to line 7 we call again `generate(1, ...)` for the same result ... and so on

```
01. function generate(n, array) {
02.     if (n == 1) {
03.         return array;
04.     }
05.     else {
06.         for (var i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
07.             generate(n - 1, array);
08.             if (n % 2 !== 0) {
09.                 swap(array[i], array[n - 1]);
10.             }
11.            else {
12.                swap(array[0], array[n - 1]);
13.            }
14.        }
15.        generate(n - 1, array);
16.    }
17. }
```

Comment: Thanks, that verified my suspicions. I'm going to go and try to walk through this. Although I'll use A,B,C,D since it's less permutations.

Comment: glad to hear. BTW, if you're learning recursion, I wouldn't suggest permutations as first lesson. Better try some factorial, fibonacci or maze. Google for "factorial recursion javascript", "fibonacci recursion javascript" and/or "2d maze recursion javascript"

Comment: Thanks. I've actually have walked through the factorial and fibonacci examples, and quickly moved on to this because it's needed for the coding challenge/task I'm doing. Thanks though, I'll check out the 2d-maze.